# 3 Strikes Query SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, datediff

I need to create a SQL query that populates a table when someone has been of 3 times or more in a 3 month period.

The data I have available to me is :

```
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1406 AS InstanceID, '2016-01-08 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-01-13 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 4 AS NoOfDays, 1 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1493 AS InstanceID, '2016-02-02 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-02-05 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 4 AS NoOfDays, 2 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1536 AS InstanceID, '2016-02-19 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-02-22 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 2 AS NoOfDays, 3 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1547 AS InstanceID, '2016-02-26 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-03-10 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 10 AS NoOfDays, 4 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1660 AS InstanceID, '2016-04-04 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-04-04 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 0.5 AS NoOfDays, 5 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1666 AS InstanceID, '2016-04-07 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-04-14 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 6 AS NoOfDays, 6 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1698 AS InstanceID, '2016-04-27 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-04-28 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 1 AS NoOfDays, 7 AS rnk
```

Which gives the below output.

[image]

I need to design a query that will flag when there are more than 3 instances within a 90 day period. So with the above date 1406,1493,1536,1547,1660,1666 would all flag up (historically). Ideally the query will run daily and set the alert as soon as a 3rd instance is logged. I’ve tried various DATEDIFF’s and derived queries but can’t seem to get it to work. 
So the desired output would be the above table but limited to those that fall within the date range of the first absence start + 90 days. I know I’m missing something simple!

Comment: what column should be compare to check if it falls in `absence start + 90 days`? Is it `AbsenceEnd`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a loop, see my code below (commented).  I put your initial data into #temp:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null
drop table #temp

SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1406 AS InstanceID, '2016-01-08 00:00:00.000' AS 

AbsenceStart, '2016-01-13 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 4 AS NoOfDays, 1 AS rnk
into #temp
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1493 AS InstanceID, '2016-02-02 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-02-05 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 4 AS NoOfDays, 2 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1536 AS InstanceID, '2016-02-19 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-02-22 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 2 AS NoOfDays, 3 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1547 AS InstanceID, '2016-02-26 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-03-10 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 10 AS NoOfDays, 4 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1660 AS InstanceID, '2016-04-04 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-04-04 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 0.5 AS NoOfDays, 5 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1666 AS InstanceID, '2016-04-07 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-04-14 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 6 AS NoOfDays, 6 AS rnk
UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Doe' AS Name, 1698 AS InstanceID, '2016-04-27 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceStart, '2016-04-28 00:00:00.000' AS AbsenceEnd, 1 AS NoOfDays, 7 AS rnk


-- First find the start rank:
declare @x int = (select top 1 rnk from #temp order by rnk asc)
-- Find the maximum number of records to loop through
declare @y int = (select top 1 rnk from #temp order by rnk desc)
-- This is your threshold for publishing
declare @a int

-- start loop
while @x <= @y


begin

if @a >=3
break; -- if threshold breached, stop loop.

else    

if object_id('tempdb..#list') is not null
drop table #list

declare @z datetime = (select AbsenceStart from #temp where rnk = @x)
print @z

select
instanceid,
AbsenceStart
into #list
from #temp
where AbsenceStart >= @z
and AbsenceStart <= dateadd(dd,90,@z)


set @a = (select count(instanceid) from #list)



set @x = @x + 1

print @x

end

insert into dbo.DestinationTable
select * 
from #list
```